# I am unable to set nfs block size to greater than 32kbps

Tags: 12.04, nfs

I am using 12.04.4 and trying to connect to a NFS server which allows a blocksize of 64kbps, but the most I can set on the client side with mount.nfs is rsize/wsize=32786. I read that there is a kernel define NFSSVC_MAXBLKSIZE that may be limited to 32k, but I am not sure this is for client or server or both.  Whichever, how can I change this, or something else to get a higher buffer size?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about this subject, but i made some research and i found that you can easily modify `rsize` and `wsize` values while mounting, **The maximum value that can be set depends on the current kernel version you have**.

Take a look at this : [How to do Linux NFS Performance Tuning and Optimization](http://www.slashroot.in/how-do-linux-nfs-performance-tuning-and-optimization)

Answer (score 0):

According to [nfs(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man5/nfs.5.html), `rsize` and `wsize` can be set to `1048576` (1 MB), which is the maximum value for the NFS client. Older NFS versions (e.g. NFSv2) had smaller max values.

This can be changed as a `mount` option, e.g.:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576 server:/data /mnt/data
```

Note: the client and server negotiate the largest rsize/wsize value that  they can both support. So, if the server doesn't support a rsize/wsize that large, a smaller one will be negotiated:

```
$ mount | grep /mnt/data | egrep -o rsize=[0-9]*
rsize=131072
```

Comment: Is there anyway to determine if the size is being set by negotiation?  Is there anyway to enable this level of debug?

Comment: "If" the size is set? The size is always negotiated, because both sides need to agree on a size. "Which" size is being set can be seen via "mount", see my answer above.

Comment: So I found that if I use 'nfsstat -m' it shows the actual buffer size that is being used.  And verified that the max allowed for me is 32k.